# How to stop user sending form if confirmation email doesnt match with email?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, salesforce

I have a web to lead form, I have to confirm email with a second email input box. If two emails equals I will let user submit the form. If not I will alert user. But even though emails are not equals form keeps sending. Can you help with this?

```
**This is form tag**
<form id="theForm"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/bla bla bla" method="POST">



**This is my submit button**
<input type="submit"  name="submit" class="submit-button" onclick={alertUser()}  >


**and this is js**

var email=document.getElementById('email');
var confirmationEmail=document.getElementById('confirmationEmail');

function validateForm(event) {

    if (email.value != confirmationEmail.value)
    {
        alert('Emails don\'t match!');
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  
}
```

I tried to add preventDefault() and return false;

Comment: Where are your email HTML elements?

Comment: <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="email" class="required">Email:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input  id="email" class="input-type" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email" required/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="confirmationEmail" class="required">Confirm Email:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input  id="confirmationEmail" class="input-type" maxlength="80" name="confirmationEmail" size="20" type="email" required/>
        </td>
    </tr>
 These are my email tags

Comment: see this codepen https://codepen.io/prasanthmj/pen/PKpaEd and put in your email checking, and, if the emails do not match, then return false.